# Function is undefined, but i had defined it

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, onload

I'm a PLC programmer, i made a html page and i need it script refresh every second, so in my body i placed:

```
    <body onload="changeimage()">

.... code ....

</body>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
setInterval(function changeimage() {
var sonde = ["Sonda1","Sonda2","Sonda3","Sonda4"];
var tsonde = ["tsonda1","tsonda2","tsonda3","tsonda4"];
var temperature = [:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda1:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda2:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda3:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda4:];
var hotcold = document.getElementById("Fiocco");
if (:="OUTPUT".Stagione.Estate: > 0){
      hotcold.src="sun.jpg"}
if (:="OUTPUT".Stagione.Inverno: > 0){
      hotcold.src="Neve.png"}    
 for (x in temperature) {
           var icona = document.getElementById(sonde[x]);
                     if (temperature[x] > 0 ){
               icona.src="Paverde.png"
           }
           else{
               icona.src="Parossa.png"
           }

     }
}, 1000);   
</script>
```

Anyway i get the error: 
ReferenceError: changeimage is not defined

P.S.: Don't get fooled by the arrays who start with ":", is a PLC syntax, is correct.

@ Even removing the setinterval option, the script is not working.

Comment: your `changeimage` function definition was inside a `setInterval`, that's why your page doesn't see that function once it's loaded. You might want to move that function outside `setIntetval`, and inside call something like `setInterval( changeimage, 1000)`

Comment: `body onload="..."` searches the specified function from the global scope only. The function you've defined is a named function expression passed as an argument to `setInterval` method. That argument is not visible to the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function first and make sure the script is loaded.

Example in code pen: https://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/NWPvQPE

```
function changeimage() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var sonde = ["Sonda1","Sonda2","Sonda3","Sonda4"];
        var tsonde = ["tsonda1","tsonda2","tsonda3","tsonda4"];
        var temperature = [:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda1:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda2:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda3:,:="OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda4:];
        var hotcold = document.getElementById("Fiocco");

        if (:="OUTPUT".Stagione.Estate: > 0){
            hotcold.src="sun.jpg"
        }
        if (:="OUTPUT".Stagione.Inverno: > 0){
            hotcold.src="Neve.png"
        }

        for (x in temperature) {
            var icona = document.getElementById(sonde[x]);
            if (temperature[x] > 0 ){
                icona.src="Paverde.png"
            }
            else{
                icona.src="Parossa.png"
            }

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @DaniloCervellini Hi, I Edit your code (above to work) and also put codepen example for simple use.

Comment: Was two problems, one is that you solved, the other is that it works only with the PLC connected (Due the ":" issue). Loading it without plc gave the same problem. Now i have a new one about image refresh but i'm looking for solutions

Comment: Good luck i happy that i could help.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway i get the error: `ReferenceError: changeimage is not defined`

```
setInterval(function changeimage() {
```

Sure it won't be `defined`, as **it was only defined as a `callback` function** to the `setInterval()` call.

So it won't be visible outside of this `setInterval` scope, and it won't be `visible` for the `onload` event listener of your `body`.

**Solution:**

You should define your `changeimage()` function in the global scope (outside of the `setInterval` like this:

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function changeimage() {
      var sonde = ["Sonda1", "Sonda2", "Sonda3", "Sonda4"];
      var tsonde = ["tsonda1", "tsonda2", "tsonda3", "tsonda4"];
      var temperature = [: = "OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda1: ,: = "OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda2: ,: = "OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda3: ,: = "OUTPUT".AlarmTemp.Sonda4: ];
      var hotcold = document.getElementById("Fiocco");
      if (: = "OUTPUT".Stagione.Estate: > 0) {
        hotcold.src = "sun.jpg"
      }
      if (: = "OUTPUT".Stagione.Inverno: > 0) {
        hotcold.src = "Neve.png"
      }
      for (x in temperature) {
        var icona = document.getElementById(sonde[x]);
        if (temperature[x] > 0) {
          icona.src = "Paverde.png"
        } else {
          icona.src = "Parossa.png"
        }

      }
    }


    setInterval(changeimage(), 1000);
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="changeimage()">

  .... code ....

</body>
```

You can see it **[working in  this Demo](https://codepen.io/chsdk/pen/VwYzomr)**.

**Note:**

Make sure to place your script tag in the `head` of your `HTML` page before the `body` tag so it can be accessed in the `onload` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function changeImage(){
  ....
}

// if you need to call every 1 sec
setInterval(changeImage,1000);

// else
changeImage();  or // setTimeout(changeImage,1000)
```

Comment: I have the same problem even if i dont put any setInterval